# Execution Error : Part of C code compiled but not being executed properly in ECM

Tags: c, matlab, gcc, embedded, compiler-optimization

I am working on ECM (using `gcc` compiler we generate the hex file and flash it on controller)

There is a code `x=(a+b)/2`, what ever the value of `a` and `b`, but the value in `x` is always zero.

I have a looping condition on `x`, which is causing my `ECM` to reset.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Things that I have tried:

1. added some redundant code just above that --> not worth, compiler optimized that
2. I suspect the optimization of compiler --> hence had a look at assembly code, but that is of no help either
3. made the variables global (before being private) --> out put is the same

Can you throw some light on what else can I try ?

That is also an autocode (using `MATLAB` modelling).

Comment: What is "ECM"? What's your code? What are the values of `a` and `b`? What are the types of `a`, `b` and `x`?

Comment: A bit more context required. @DKrueger 's answer may well be right, but it remains a guess (unless he knows something about MATLAB's code generation). Does the code work when not compiler-optimised?  In it does then DKrueger is probably on the money.

Answer (score 0):

Add `volatile` qualifiers to the declarations of `a` and `b`.